# Añadir condicion a Combobox generado en tiempo de ejecucion

Tags: c#, windows-forms, eventos, condiciones, combobox

soy muy novato en C# ando aprendiendo por mi cuenta, el problema es que cuento con un boton que cuando lo presiono genera un text box y tres combobox ademas pre carga valores en el primer combobox(mybox), pero no logro ponerle adecuadamente condicion al otro combobox(mybox1) y mucho menos a cada nueva fila que genero. Creo que estoy referenciando mal los condicionales del switch pero me encuentro atorado visualizando como podria proceder, anexo codigo e imagenes, cualquier guia es altamente agradecida al igual que su paciencia.

[image: Forma que manejo]

Cada que se presiona el boton mas filas genera las formas

Codigo del boton filas

```
    public int iniptb = 16;
    public int inipcb1 = 80;
    public int inipcb2 = 200;
    public int inipcb3 = 325;
    public int endpoint =55;

private void btFilas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        TextBox myText = new TextBox();
        myText.Location = new Point(iniptb, endpoint);
        myText.Size = new Size(50, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(myText);
        ComboBox myBox = new ComboBox();
        myBox.Location = new Point(inipcb1, endpoint);
        myBox.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        myBox.Items.Add("Manual");
        myBox.Items.Add("Automatico");
        myBox.Items.Add("Neumatico");
        this.Controls.Add(myBox);
        ComboBox myBox1 = new ComboBox();
        myBox1.Location = new Point(inipcb2, endpoint);
        myBox1.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(myBox1);
        ComboBox myBox2 = new ComboBox();
        myBox2.Location = new Point(inipcb3, endpoint);
        myBox2.Size = new Size(100, 20);
        this.Controls.Add(myBox2);
        endpoint += 25;
    }
```

Esta es la funcion con la que intento que el primer combo box (herramienta) me de valores en el segundo combobox(componente) pero no me funciona

```
    private void myBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox myText = new TextBox();
        ComboBox myBox = new ComboBox();
        ComboBox myBox1 = new ComboBox();
        ComboBox myBox2 = new ComboBox();

        switch (myBox.Text)
        {
            case ("Manual"):
            myBox1.Items.Clear();
            myBox1.Items.Add("Pin");
            myBox1.Items.Add("Socket");
            myBox1.Items.Add("Terminal");
            myBox1.Items.Add("Barril");

         break;
            case ("Automatica"):
         myBox1.Items.Clear();
         myBox1.Items.Add("Pin");
         break;
            case ("Neumatica"):
         myBox1.Items.Clear();
         myBox1.Items.Add("Pin");
         myBox1.Items.Add("Terminal");
           break;
        }
    }
```

Tal vez me este complicando y pueda haber otra alternativa mas sencilla
lo hago así porque ya que se llenen esas formas planeo utilizar esa información para otro procedimiento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una opción a lo que planteas es lo siguiente:

```
public int iniptb = 16;
public int inipcb1 = 80;
public int inipcb2 = 200;
public int inipcb3 = 325;
public int endpoint =55;
private void btFilas_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    TextBox myText = new TextBox();
    myText.Location = new Point(iniptb, endpoint);
    myText.Size = new Size(50, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(myText);
    ComboBox myBox = new ComboBox();
    myBox.Location = new Point(inipcb1, endpoint);
    myBox.Size = new Size(100, 20);
    myBox.Items.Add("Manual");
    myBox.Items.Add("Automatico");
    myBox.Items.Add("Neumatico");
    this.Controls.Add(myBox);
    ComboBox myBox1 = new ComboBox();
    myBox1.Location = new Point(inipcb2, endpoint);
    myBox1.Size = new Size(100, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(myBox1);
    ComboBox myBox2 = new ComboBox();
    myBox2.Location = new Point(inipcb3, endpoint);
    myBox2.Size = new Size(100, 20);
    this.Controls.Add(myBox2);
    endpoint += 25;

    //GUARDO UNA REFERENCIA A myBox1 EN LA PROPIEDAD myBox.Tag
    myBox.Tag = myBox1;
    //Y AGREGO EL MANEJADOR DE EVENTOS
    myBox.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(myBox_SelectedIndexChanged);
}
```

Para el segundo metodo:

```
private void myBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //ESTO ESTÁ MAL
    //    TextBox myText = new TextBox();
    //    ComboBox myBox = new ComboBox();
    //    ComboBox myBox1 = new ComboBox();
    //    ComboBox myBox2 = new ComboBox();
    //HASTA ACÁ, PUES LO QUE HACES ES CREAR NUEVOS OBJETOS Y NO REFERENCIANDO LOS QUE YA HAS CREADO PARA ESA FILA

    //POR ESTA RAZÓN REFERENCIÉ myBox1 EN LA PROPIEDAD myBox.Tag

    ComboBox myBox = (ComboBox)sender;
    ComboBox myBox1 = (ComboBox)myBox.Tag;

    //sender ES EL CONTROL SOBRE EL QUE SE PRODUCE EL EVENTO QUE INVOCA ESTE MÉTODO, ASÍ QUE SERÍA myBox DE ESTE MODO myBox1 ESTÁ REFERENCIADO EN myBox.Tag


    //ESTAS DOS INTRUCCIONES SE REPITEN EN TODOS LOS CASOS, PUEDES DEJARLAS GLOBALMENTE
    myBox1.Items.Clear();
    myBox1.Items.Add("Pin");

    switch (myBox.Text)
    {
        case ("Manual"):
            myBox1.Items.Add("Socket");
            myBox1.Items.Add("Barril");
            //AQUÍ OMITO break, PUESTO QUE Terminal SE ENCUENTRA EN LOS CASOS Manual Y Neumática
        case ("Neumatica"):
            myBox1.Items.Add("Terminal");
            break;
    }
}
```

Y creo que eso es todo. Espero sea de ayuda.

Te recomiendo que si lo que quieres es hacer alimentar una tabla de datos es mejor que uses el control DataGridView o puedes seguir así pero crea una instancia `List<System.Windows.Control[]>` y lleva orden de los controles que pertenecen a cada fila...

Comment: Te comento aquí porque has borrado todo rastro de tu presencia en la otra pregunta. Por favor, deja de usar las mayúsculas por defecto. Si todos los comentarios están en mayúsculas... no destacan. Y ante una crítica tienes 3 caminos: no hacer caso, borrar la respuesta y editarla... no veo motivos que te *obliguen* a optar por la segunda opción.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, me aclaro algunas dudas aparte de la que ya tenia, no estoy muy familiarizado con el event handler y ando aprendiendo a usar el datagrid view creo que buscare otro enfoque y me sera menos complicado que lo que estoy intentando.

Comment: Me alegra ser de ayuda, amigo @Javier

Comment: @DanielPérez si alguien te pone un -1 y arreglas lo que ha motivado esa puntuación es bastante probable que ese -1 se convierta en un +1 con la posibilidad de sumar otros votos positivos. Si borras la respuesta te comes el -1 y no obtienes puntos positivos

Comment: @eferion Pudiste solo hacer el comentario y lo habría tomado en cuenta de inmediato... En unos minutos recupero la publicación con sus respectivas modificaciones.

Comment: @DanielPérez no te conozco ni quien ha preguntado tampoco, poner puntos negativos da idea al lector que la respuesta puede no set todo lo correcta que le gustaría. Si quieres un consejo, no te agobies por la puntuación. Si escribes buenas respuestas, la puntuación llegará sola

Comment: @eferion Con que me dejes en 0 por mi está bien.

Comment: @DanielPérez eso es tan sencillo de conseguir como revivir la respuesta y editarla para que cumpla

Comment: @eferion lo hice antes de escribir ese comentario, revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270021/c-error-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type/270034#270034