# C error : dereferencing pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c

```
unsigned int method(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    struct power *p1,*p2,*p3;
    unsigned int i,x=1;

    for(i=2; i<a/2; i++){
        while((a%i)==0){
           if(p1->base!=i){
              p1->base=i;

    struct power{
        int base;
        int index;
};
```

Tengo un problema con el código:
En las siguientes lineas me genera el mismo error

```
if(p1->base!=i){                                                    
p1->base=i;
```

¿Qué puedo hacer para que no me genere este error al compilar?

Comment: @DanielPérez No veo qué te obliga, según tu, a borrar la respuesta. La borras porque quieres. También podrías haber optado por editar la respuesta y adaptarla. Que el código no tenga formato no es excusa para abusar de las mayúsculas o, dicho de otra forma, si tu tienes 10 tareas y todas son urgentísimas, realmente no hay ninguna urgente porque todas tienen la misma prioridad... si usas mayúsculas para enfatizar **todo** entonces nada destaca porque todo son mayúsculas.

Comment: Por otro lado, nadie te obliga a usar comentarios en el código... puedes despiezar el código y comentar paquetes de líneas con texto normal con el formato que te de la gana

Answer (score 1):

En C, existen dos formas de dar a conocer un tipo de datos al compilador:

- Declaración: Le dices al compilador que un tipo de datos existe, pero no entras en detalles de cómo es.
- Definición: Le dices al compilador que un tipo de datos existe y describes su estructura interna. Cuenta también como Declaración si el tipo no había sido declarado.

Los tipos Declarados se consideran incompletos porque el compilador no sabe su estructura interna y en consecuencia no sabe su tamaño. C permite crear punteros a tipos Declarados (incompletos) porque para apuntar a los datos de estos tipos no necesita conocer su tamaño; pero en el momento en que se intente acceder a los datos apuntados el compilador necesitará consultar la Definición, que de no estar disponible se quejará de que el tipo es incompleto, , eso es lo que te está pasando:

```
struct power *p1,*p2,*p3;
\\     ^^^^^ <--- DECLARACION de la estructura llamda 'power'
unsigned int i,x=1;

for (i=2; i<a/2; i++) {
    while((a%i)==0) {
       if(p1->base!=i) {
\\          ^^ <--- ACCESO al interior de la estructura 'power', pero es incompleta
          p1->base=i;
\\          ^^ <--- ACCESO al interior de la estructura 'power', pero es incompleta

   struct power{
       int base;
       int index;
   };
\\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- DEFINICIÓN de la estructura 'power'.
```

El problema es que Defines después de usar, si cambias el orden tu problema se resuelve:

```
   struct power{
       int base;
       int index;
   };
\\ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--- DEFINICIÓN de la estructura 'power'.

struct power *p1,*p2,*p3;
\\     ^^^^^ <--- DECLARACION de la estructura llamda 'power', ya está definida
unsigned int i,x=1;

for (i=2; i<a/2; i++) {
    while((a%i)==0) {
       if(p1->base!=i) {
\\          ^^ <--- ACCESO al interior de la estructura 'power', está completa
          p1->base=i;
\\          ^^ <--- ACCESO al interior de la estructura 'power', está completa
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé si has copiado mal el código en tu pregunta. Si no es así deberías hacer un buen uso con las llaves para así evitar numerosos problemas de compilación.

```
struct power{
    int base;
    int index;
};

unsigned int method(unsigned int a, unsigned int b){
    struct power *p1,*p2,*p3;
    unsigned int i,x=1;

    for (i=2; i<a/2; i++) {
        while((a%i)==0) {
           if(p1->base!=i) {
              p1->base=i;
           } <--------------------------------- END IF
        } <--------------------------------- END WHILE
    } <--------------------------------- END FOR
} <--------------------------------- END METHOD
```

Comment: Esto no responde a la pregunta (en realidad soluciona el problema pero no explica por qué).